# Allow user to select webpage element directly from URL within Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, element

I've been trying to find a way to allow a user to select an element on a webpage within Python.

In the below code you can see I've pre-defined an element. What I want is the user to be able to hover over the element on a webpage and click it, which then returns a value to python. Very similar to the element selector within chrome.

Is this possible? Any ideas

```
element = f"#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child({nth}) > button"
```

*(ps I have imported BeautifulSoup4 and Selenium to help **scrape** the webpage)*

Thanks

Ginge

Comment: What exactly do you want to return after hovering over an element and clicking it?

Answer (score 0):

To hover over an element and click it you may use the following code:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('f"#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child({nth}) > button"')
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```